# How do you load a React component when Button is clicked?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, onclick

I have a Nav bar button that when clicked opens a drawer that contains tabs explaining several products or solutions available. Currently the Navbar and Drawer are in one component to allow it to work and show what my ultimate goal is. However, I want to separate the drawer component out so that one file contains the Navbar, one contains the Drawer, and one has the Vertical Tabs and render the drawer component when the the button is clicked.

Also, is there a way to maybe use 1 drawer component that would dynamically update the tabs depending if i clicked the Product or Solutions tab?

here is my code Sandbox i have set up for this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-click-and-render-components-444rxd?file=/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following these steps:

Create Separate Components:

Create separate components for Navbar, Drawer, and Vertical Tabs.

Navbar Component (Navbar.tsx):

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Toolbar, AppBar } from "@mui/material";

interface NavbarProps {
  onProductsClick: () => void;
  onSolutionsClick: () => void;
}

function Navbar({ onProductsClick, onSolutionsClick }) {
  // Navbar code
}
export default Navbar;
```

Drawer Component (Drawer.tsx):

```
import React from "react";
import { Drawer } from "@mui/material";

interface DrawerProps {
  open: boolean;
  onClose: () => void;
}

function CustomDrawer({ open, onClose, children }) {
  // Drawer code
}
export default CustomDrawer;
```

Parent Component:

Create a parent component that manages the state and renders Navbar, Drawer, and Vertical Tabs.

```
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import CustomDrawer from "./Drawer";
import ProdVertTabs from "./ProdVertTabs";
import SoluVertTabs from "./SoluVertTabs";

function TopNav() {
  const [productsNav, setProductsNav] = useState(false);
  const [solutionsNav, setSolutionsNav] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Box>
      <Navbar
        onProductsClick={() => setProductsNav(true)}
        onSolutionsClick={() => setSolutionsNav(true)}
      />

      <CustomDrawer open={productsNav} onClose={() => setProductsNav(false)}>
        <ProdVertTabs />
      </CustomDrawer>

      <CustomDrawer open={solutionsNav} onClose={() => setSolutionsNav(false)}>
        <SoluVertTabs />
      </CustomDrawer>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

You may need to make some changes to this as per your use

---

Comment: what do i set for the onClick event under the buttons to trigger the open of the drawer?

Comment: So when as you can see

 onProductsClick: () => void;
  onSolutionsClick: () => void;

these two are props so use then on the respective onClick in Navbar.tsx

as i told i just gave you the idea of doing it you have to make edits depending on the use case